# How to activate Steam review comments by default?

Tags: steam

Comments on Steam reviews have been deactivated by default. If I want people to be able to comment on my review I have to click the check box to activate comments. I want all my future and past reviews to have comments activated. Is there an option to change the default to active?

Comment: *"I want all my future and past reviews to have comments activated"* - past reviews do not have comments disabled. And it takes very little to learn to enable comments for new reviews. But yeah, it would be [QOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_of_life) improvement if I could opt-out from disabled by default comments, which Steam developers unfortunately ignoring for decades.

Comment: I meant my past comments of the last year since April 2018. They do have comments disabled by default. I know how to enable comments I just don't think of it for every review I write. Maybe Steam will look harder into QOL when Epic Store is strong enough a challenger.

Answer (score 1):

**Steam [disabled](https://www.vg247.com/2018/04/26/steam-reviews-comments-disabled-by-default/) [them](https://www.pcgamesn.com/steam-review-comments-disabled) by [default](https://www.reddit.com/r/Steam/comments/8eq1cv/comments_are_now_disabled_by_default_on_new_steam/) because of the new data privacy laws, like the [GDPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation)**.
It got changed around the time the GDPR took effect in April 2018.

I wasn't able to find a link to an official statement on the matter by Steam itself, but did find [a related message](https://steamcommunity.com/games/593110/announcements/detail/1667896941884942467) on what I think might be that particular update.

Nor was I able to find a way to fix this, but, considering the comments and the age of the links, I presume there currently is no tweak to change the setting.

[Here](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/10/1736588252394320481/?ctp=3)'s a Steam thread where people comment on disabling comments, in case you're interested.

Comment: I wonder why this is written as an answer. OP didn't ask for reasons nor you actually able to provide them. Should be a comment.

Comment: Because, as addressed, there is no way to disable them (well, being software, there *probably* is a way, albeit very hard). It would make little sense to not answer any question that is based on mistaken premises.

Comment: Ah, so it's a "no" answer. But it's very uncertain "no" and in the third paragraph... doesn't really sounds like a solid answer worth posting ;)

Comment: You're right about that, but usually under these circumstances if long-winded threads on different popular websites offer no solutions, one hasn't been found. But you may always improve on my answer :)

Comment: Thanks! Then it seems to be not possible at the moment.